# How can I share a created google maps in my site to another site

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, symfony-2.1

I have a site where I create personalized google maps. I create some points, some routes. And, in my site I can save those maps. 
The point is, how can I do to share those maps in order they can be used, managed for a user in other site.

Example:
I´m an user that create some routes. I export those routes(maps) in some format and I want to paste this in other site in order the second site can be able to see and manage(if possible) the map that I have share in my main site.

Please, any clue will be appreciated....

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty open question. Before all, you and your friend should use the same app or at least agree on certain comventions.  For example
- the map will be a json with properties such as latn lng and zoom. 
- Another properties should yield strings, integers, floats, arrays and objects
- among objects, there could be some mcarrays, circles, polygons, etc. All of them have a map property that would throw a circular reference if you try to stringify the map.

There are a lot of other comventions to make in order to be able to flatten the map to make it stringifiable, and on the other side, the equivalent to rebuild the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the map in xml and then create a map on the other website using that XML. The following link details how this can be done using PHP and MySQL. https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3?hl=en